# How to stretch an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

All,

I need to know how to stretch an image for further work.

for example, I have the next two images:

[image]  [image]

I want that the numbers will fill the entire square like this:

[image] [image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the background is a constant value, and that the image doesn't have any constant rows, cols, and that the useful image is a rectangle in the middle of the larger image with background:

```
colsWithImg = find(any(abs(diff(img)))); % idxs of cols with any img in it.
rowsWithImg = find(any(abs(diff(img'))));
imgWithNoBG = img(min(rowsWithImg):max(rowsWithImg),min(colsWithImg):max(colsWithImg));
% this will also work: but you will lose any constant rows / cols
% imgWithNoBG = img(rowsWithImg,colsWithImg);
```

Now that you have an image with no background it is easy to stretch it using imresize, assuming you have the imageprocessing toolbox.

```
resizedImg = imrezize(imgWithNoBG,newSize);
```

To remove the artifact, first descritize the extracted character:

```
descImg = floor((nDescLevels*imgWithNoBg)/max(max(imgWithNoBg)))
colsNoArtifact = find(any(abs(diff(descImg))));
rowsNoArtifact = find(any(abs(diff(descImg'))));
```

And then extract the correct rows from the non descritized image

```
img3 = imgWithNoBG(min(rowsNoArtifact):max(rowsNoArtifact),min(colsNoArtifact):max(colsNoArtifact));
```

Lowering the number of descritization levels will help to remove more of the artifact, but will make it more likely to mistakenly remove part of the character.  I also forsee some problems with numbers like 1 or 7 where part of the character can be mistaken for artifact.

Comment: @BlessedKey Thanks for your help but it does not help me. I'm getting exactly what I had before. this is probably because there is black lines at the top of the image. any suggestions?

Comment: @Michael  Hrm.  It sounds like you want to separate the "number" part from the "artifact" or "noise" part.  Doing this with arbitrary types of noise will require some type of OCR.  A fast and easy hack can be done IF you can assume that the artifacts look like a bar at the top/bottom or left/right of the image.  Simply repeat the background removal process I outlined above, but only on the extracted image.   If there are small variations within the artifacts, you can try quantizing the image into a small number of gray levels first.  

I've edited the reply to reflect this.

Comment: @BlessedKey now it's indeed cutting the black lines, but what is the value of nDescLevels, is there some way to konw his value for every image? like you said comment before if it can cut part of a number it's not so good, so this is works only for this case. thanks again

Comment: There is probably not one value that will work for every type of artifact.  Smaller values are more likely to remove the artifact, but also more likely to cut out parts of the digit.  A more sophisticated solution might cluster the pixel values and replace values with cluster indexes, making it more likely that the entire artifact is the same value.  Is this for an OCR application?  If you like the answer please credit.

Comment: @Michael in your OCR application, if you have the computational resources, you might try multiple discretization parameters to see which response gives you the highest **confidence**.   Also I notice that the artifact seems to usually only occupy the top of the image.  You might consider modeling the profile of the extracted characters, labeling the location of the end of the artifact by hand, and training a machine learning algorithm to detect the artifact boundary.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The background of the image is black? White? 
Find the smallest rectangle which encloses the image. And cut the borders by the command img(uppixel:downpoxil, leftpixel:rightpixel)

You find the smallest rectangle by for loop and compare each pixel not in background against the border

Comment: what do you mean by "compare each pixel not in background against the border". as you see there is black line on the upper side of the image what I think could cause trouble. can you give me some kind of code example please? thanks...